# check if user following to post author django

Tags: django, django-models

I am creating blogging website. where user can like, bookmark Post and follow User/Post-writer.
What i want is when requesting blog by slug url. it also check if requested user has liked that post and bookmarked that post and also check whether if user following to author or not.

how should i apply following logic logic?

**CustomUser Model**

```
class CustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True, null=True, blank= True)
    ....
    ....
    followers = models.ManyToManyField("self",blank=True, symmetrical=True , related_name='user_follower')
```

**Blog Model**

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=300, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey("accounts.CustomUser", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    likes = models.ManyToManyField(Blog, blank=True, related_name="users_likes")
    ....
    ....
```

```
    def get(self, request):
        print("slugggggggggggggg", request.query_params['slug'])
        query = Blog.objects.annotate(
            #also not working
            liked=Case(
                When(users_likes=request.user.id, then=Value(True)),
                default=Value(False),
            ),
            # following is not working
            # following=Case(
            #     When(author__user_follower=request.user.id, then=Value(True)),
            #     default=Value(False),
            # ),
            total_likes=Count('users_likes'),
                about=F('author__about'), 
            followers_number=Count('author__followers'),
            ).get(status=True, slug=request.query_params['slug'])
        serializer = BlogUserSerializer(query)
        return Response(serializer.data,)
```

Comment: I think **Blog** should have **likes**, and **bookmarks** instead of user

Comment: thanks @AnkitTiwari but can you tell me how should implement following logic